# Wireless setting -WPA2 Enterprise 

Tags: 11.04, networking, wireless, security, wpa2

I'm setting my wireless environment.
I have to use WPA2 Enterprise with PEAP and **have to use AES encryption**.
But I can't find where encryption config is. (MS-Windows has the option)
How can I config it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this link you will see that AES encryption is part of the WPA2 Enterprise protocol.

[WiFi Protected Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access)

Note the heading: Version

> WPA2: Also known as IEEE 802.11i-2004. Successor of WPA, and replaces
>   the TKIP encryption protocol with CCMP to provide additional security.
>   Mandatory for Wi-Fi–certified devices since 2006.

And the heading: Encryption protocol CCMP

> An AES-based encryption mechanism that is stronger than TKIP.
>   Sometimes referred to as AES instead of CCMP. Used by WPA2.

This is why Kevin in his answer is able to say that he never has a problem connecting even though he has to meet the same requirements as you.

Answer (score 1):

My work wireless network has all the same settings including AES.  I never have a problem connecting.  It makes me login twice.  I am guessing it is trying different options.  But after the second login I am connected.